# Implementation of atoi()

Tags: c, parsing, reinventing-the-wheel, integer

I implemented the `atoi()` function! Here is my code:

```
int my_atoi(char* pointer)
{
    int result = 0;
    char* pointer1;
    multiplier = 1;
    char sign = 1;

    if(*pointer == '-')
    sign =- 1;  

    pointer1 = pointer;

    while(*pointer != '\0')
    {
        if(*pointer >= '0' && *pointer <= '9')
            multiplier = multiplier * 10;

        pointer = pointer + 1;  
    }

    pointer = pointer1;

    while(*pointer != '\0')
    {       
        if(*pointer >= '0' && *pointer <= '9')
        {
            result = result + ( (*pointer%48)  * multiplier);
            multiplier = multiplier / 10;       
        }

        pointer = pointer+1;
    }

    return (result * sign) / 10;
}
```

I wonder if there is any way that I can improve my function. I know there is a problem with my function. What if the user wants to convert from `char*` to `int` this string: "232-19". What should I do then? Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: how is the problem "string to int: 232-19" connected with the code at hand?

Comment: Well what if i want to convert from string to int the number -255 and by accident i type "8-255" .Then according to my algorith the number 8255 will be returned.I know it's pretty stupid to worry about these things but what if the user is extremely dumb? Furthermore i know it is really difficult for someone to type 8-255 instead of -255 but you never know, it may happen!

Comment: raise an error. the input format is faulty. you shouldn't guess what the user wanted, but make him make his intent unmistakably clear ;)

Comment: You only need one pass of the string (not two).

Comment: Please do not edit your code after it has been reviewed so that it could make any reviews irrelevant.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Things you could improve

#### Variables/Initialization

- Where do you declare `multiplier`?  I assume that since it is not declared within the method, it is declared as a global variable.  Try to avoid global variables.

  The problem with global variables is that since every function has access to these, it becomes increasingly hard to figure out which functions actually read and write these variables.

  To understand how the application works, you pretty much have to take into account every function which modifies the global state. That can be done, but as the application grows it will get harder to the point of being virtually impossible (or at least a complete waste of time).

  If you don't rely on global variables, you can pass state around between different functions as needed. That way you stand a much better chance of understanding what each function does, as you don't need to take the global state into account.

  So instead of using global variables, initialize the variables in `main()`, and pass them as arguments to functions if necessary.  In this case, I don't see the need for `multiplier` to be used outside of the function at all, so simply keep it declared within the function.
- `sign` should be an `int`, and not a `char`.

#### Algorithm

- Right now you are implementing a complicated and hard to follow method of converting a character into a number.  The easy way is to have [`isdigit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) do the hard work for you.  This also will help you implement the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

  > ```
  > while(*pointer != '\0')
  > {
  >     if(*pointer >= '0' && *pointer <= '9')
  >         multiplier = multiplier * 10;
  >
  >     pointer = pointer + 1;  
  > }
  >
  > pointer = pointer1;
  >
  > while(*pointer != '\0')
  > {       
  >     if(*pointer >= '0' && *pointer <= '9')
  >     {
  >         result = result + ( (*pointer%48)  * multiplier);
  >         multiplier = multiplier / 10;       
  >     }
  >
  >     pointer = pointer+1;
  > }
  > ```

  See how you have two loops doing almost identical things?  Here is how I simplified all of that by using `isdigit()`.

  ```
  while (isdigit(*c)) 
  {
      value *= 10;
      value += (int) (*c - '0');
      c++;
  }
  ```

  You loop through the characters in the string as long as they are digits. For each one, add to the counter you're keeping - the value to add is the integer value of the character. This is done by subtracting the ASCII value of `'0'` from the ascii value of the digit in question.
- Note that this code doesn't handle overflow. If you pass in "89384798719061231" (which won't fit in an `int`), the result is undefined.  The fix is simple enough, just use a `long long int` to mitigate against that.  We'll still have issues for extremely long numbers, but fixing that so that the function works as intended is a bit more complicated.

#### Documentation

- Where did all of your comments go?  A newer developer would simply gawk at some of your code.

  > ```
  > result = result + ( (*pointer%48)  * multiplier);
  > ```

  Comments can really go a long way into helping other understand your code.  Don't go overboard with them though, you will have to balance how much of them to put into your program.

#### Syntax/Styling

- This looks like a typo.

  > ```
  > if(*pointer == '-')
  >     sign =- 1;
  > ```

  Add a space for clarity.

  ```
  if(*pointer == '-') sign = -1;
  ```
- You should **not** be modifying your `char*` you accept as a parameter into the function. Therefore, declare the parameter as constant.

  ```
  int my_atoi(const char* pointer)
  ```
- Use more shorthand operators.

  ```
  pointer++;         // same as pointer = pointer+1;
  multiplier /= 10;  // same as multiplier = multiplier / 10;
  multiplier *= 10;  // same as multiplier = multiplier * 10;
  ```

## Final Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>

long long int my_atoi(const char *c)
{
    long long int value = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    if( *c == '+' || *c == '-' )
    {
        if( *c == '-' ) sign = -1;
        c++;
    }
    while (isdigit(*c))
    {
        value *= 10;
        value += (int) (*c-'0');
        c++;
    }
    return (value * sign);
}

int main(void)
{
    assert(5 == my_atoi("5"));
    assert(-2 == my_atoi("-2"));
    assert(-1098273980709871235 == my_atoi("-1098273980709871235"));
    puts("All good."); // I reach this statement on my system
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't change return types arbitrarily.  `atoi()`  traditionally returns an `int`, so `my_atoi()` should, too. If you want to parse a `long long`, then emulate `strtoll()`.

Comment: `isdigit(*c)` is not define for `*c` values less than 0 (other than EOF).  Better to `while (isdigit((unsigned char) (*c)  ))`

Comment: Missed corner: When `my_atoi()` result should be `LLONG_MIN`, `value += (int) (*c-'0');` is signed integer overflow (UB) as it tries to form `LLONG_MAX + 1`.

Comment: Using `isdigit` is wrong at all, since it doesn't have a related function `numeric_value`. Therefore, if your character set has two ranges of digits (0 to 9, and ٠ to ٩), the Indic numbers will be parsed wrong. Just stick to `'0' <= c && c <= '9'` to be safe. This also avoids the undefined behavior from using the ctype function incorrectly.

Comment: You missed an important point when you wrote _"ASCII value of '0'"_: there's nothing that says the host character set needs to be ASCII (only that 0..9 are contiguous).  That's why you write `'0'` rather than an encoding-specific codepoint number.

Comment: Not only is `=-` a likely typo, it has a very different meaning in early dialects of C (where it meant the same as modern `-=`).

Comment: I would add a "sanity check" at the beginning of the function to make sure that `c` is not NULL (otherwise, in the first if `if( *c == '+' || *c == '-' )` you will crash).

Answer (score 6):

[Edit]

Except for the behavior on error, `atoi()` is equivalent to  `(int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`.  `strtol()` accepts leading white space.  OP's `my_atoi(char* pointer)` does not.  To remedy:

```
int my_atoi(const char* pointer) {
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *pointer)) {
    pointer++;
  }
  ...
```

The below does describe a good way to handle `INT_MIN`.

OTOH, handing values outside `[INT_MIN...INT_MAX]` is is not defined by the C spec, so some simplifications can be had.  See far below.

---

When a string represents `INT_MIN`, (let's assume 32-bit `int`) such as `"-2147483648"`, code runs into `int` overflow attempting to get to calculate `2147483648`.  A simple way to solver this is rather than finding the positive value and then negating it, embrace the **negative side** of things.  By doing the lion share of the math in the `INT_MIN` to `0` range, we avoid UB.  Down-side: some find this approach more challenging to follow.

Going to a wider integer or `unsigned` it not always possible as the integer size of "text--> integer" routine may be the maximum size.  Strictly speaking `unsigned` does not always have a wider positive range than `int`.  In any case, all the math can be handled at the desired signed integer size without resorting to other types.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int my_atoi(const char* pointer) { // good idea to make the `const`
  int result = 0;
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *pointer)) {
    pointer++;
  }
  char sign = *pointer;
  if (*pointer == '-' || *pointer == '+') {  // text could lead with a '+'
    pointer++;
  }
  int ch;
  // isdigit() expects an unsigned char or EOF, not char
  while ((ch = (unsigned char)(*pointer)) != 0) {
    if (!isdigit(ch)) break;
    ch -= '0';
    // Will overflow occur?
    if ((result < INT_MIN/10) || 
        (result == INT_MIN/10  && ch > -(INT_MIN%10))) Handle_Overflow(); 
    result *= 10;
    result -= ch;  // - , not +
    pointer++;
    }
  if (sign != '-') {
    if (result < -INT_MAX) Handle_Overflow();
    result = -result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Notes:

`pointer%48` is confusing.  What is special about 48?  If you mean `'0'`, then use `pointer % '0'`.

"string: "232-19". What should I do then?"  Recommend stopping conversion at "232" and returning the value 232.  *Could* set `errno`, but the typical `atoi()` function does not do too much error handling.

On overflow, setting `errno`, could happen, but again, typical `atoi()` function does not do too much error handling.  Suggest simple returning `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN`.

If you want better error handling, change to something like the following and set an error status.

```
int my_atoi(const char *s, int *ErrorCode);
```

**or** location where things ended.  If this are good, they ended at the `'\0'`.

```
int my_atoi(const char *s, const char **endptr);
```

---

[Edit] Simplified: Removed out-of-range detection as C spec allows that.  "If the value of the result cannot be represented, the behavior is undefined.

```
int my_atoi(const char* pointer) {
  int result = 0;
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *pointer)) {
    pointer++;
  }
  char sign = *pointer;
  if (*pointer == '-' || *pointer == '+') {
    pointer++;
  }
  while (isdigit((unsigned char)*pointer)) {
    result = result*10 - (*pointer++ - '0');
    }
  if (sign != '-') {
    result = -result;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: `INT_MIN/10` and `INT_MIN%10` require C99 behavior.

Answer (score 3):

```
  char sign = *pointer;
  if (*pointer == '-' || *pointer == '+') {
    pointer++;
  }
```

Why de-referencing "pointer" three times? One time is enough:

```
  char sign = *pointer;
  if (sign == '-' || sign == '+') {
    pointer++;
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, your first answer looks good, enjoy your stay! Though I wonder if it makes a difference in the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are ok with recursion then code could be shortened to one  below

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int natural_number(const char* string) {
    int index = strlen(string) - 1;
    int number = pow(10, index) * (*string - '0');

    return (index == 0) ? number : number + natural_number(string + 1);
}

int my_atoi(const char* string) {
    int sign = (*string == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    int offset = (*string == '-') ? 1 : 0;

    return sign * natural_number(string + offset);
}

/* test cases */
my_atoi("-100") == -100;
my_atoi("0") == 0;
my_atoi("100") == 100;
```

Stack exhaustion could be mitigated by `-foptimize-sibling-calls` compiler flag, that being supported by both GCC and Clang compilers.

**Update:**

As noted by *Roland Illig* implementation does not handle malformed input.
If it is desired closelly follow `atoi` [semantics](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) then next code should be [fine](http://tpcg.io/9ImVAz) <sub>don't forget set `Compile Options` to one in comments</sub>.

```
int digit(char symbol) {
    return symbol - '0';
}

/* tail call optimized */
int natural_number_tc(const char* string, int number) {
    return !isdigit(*string)
           ? number
           : natural_number_tc(string + 1, 10 * number + digit(*string));
}

int natural_number(const char* string) {
    return natural_number_tc(string, 0);
}

const char* left_trim_tc(const char* string, const char* symbol) {
    return !isspace(*string)  ? symbol : left_trim_tc(string + 1, symbol + 1);
}

const char* left_trim(const char* string) {
    return left_trim_tc(string, string);

}

int my_atoi(const char* string) {
    const char* symbol = left_trim(string);
    int sign = (*symbol == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    size_t offset = (*symbol == '-' || *symbol == '+') ? 1 : 0;

    return sign * natural_number(symbol + offset);
}
```

This is still *chux*'s code where loops replaced with recursion

```
int result = 0;
while (isdigit((unsigned char)*pointer)) {
  result = 10 * result + (*pointer - '0');
  pointer++;
}

// VS

int loop(const char* pointer, int result) {
  return !isdigit((unsigned char)*pointer)
         ? result
         : loop(pointer + 1, 10 * result + (*pointer - '0'))
}
```

Comment: Test case: `buf = malloc(65536); buf[0] = '\0'; my_atoi(buf)` will probably crash.

Comment: Test case: `bufsize = 1 << 20; buf = malloc(bufsize); memset(buf, '0', bufsize); buf[bufsize - 1] = '\0'; my_atoi(buf)` will take a _very_ long time.

Answer (score -1):

For a exercise in [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/description/), wrote following impl: [atoi cpp code](https://pastebin.com/dPJhsUnb)

```
    class Solution {
private:
    bool checkMin(int a,  int b=10, int c=0, int min_val=INT_MIN) {
        /*
        accepts a*b + c, min
        a>min; b>min; c>min
        check a*b+c > min or not
        b>0; a<0 -ive; c<0
        a!=0
        */

        min_val = min_val  -c;

        //std::cout<<"new min input:  "<<a <<" , "<< c<<"   iter: "<<b << "    "<<min_val <<std::endl;

        //compare with a now
        if(a<min_val)
            return false;
        int cur_prod = 0;
        if(a==0)
            return true;
        for(;b>1;b--) {
            cur_prod += a;
           int curr_diff = min_val-cur_prod; 
            /*
            subtraction possible because 
                min_val<prod,
                min_val-prod<prod-prod 
                min_val-prod<0 ---1
                prod<0
                -prod>0
                min_val+(-prod )> min_val+0 [x+ (+ive quantity)>x ]
                min_val-prod>min_val --2
                from 1, 2
                min_val< min_val-prod < 0 ---3
                from 3, min_val-prod can be expressed in integer

            check if curr_diff still can hold a deduction of a
            which means: curr_diff<a should hold, for a further a deduction in prod
                         -5, -6
                            for ex of min_val = 59, a = -6 at b = 2 (9th iteration) prod = -54
                            you can't add -6 now, since it will cross definable limit
            only b-1 iterations
            because at i-1 th iteration, ith product formation is checked
            */
            //std::cout<<"check function for input:  "<<a <<" , "<< c<<"   iter: "<<b << " prod now = "
                    //<< cur_prod << "   diff = " <<curr_diff<<"  is curr_dif<a "<<(curr_diff<a)<<std::endl;
            if(curr_diff>a) {
                //std::cout<<" not possible"<<std::endl;
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    bool checkMax(int a,  int b=10, int c=0, int max_val=INT_MAX) {
        /*
        accepts a*b + c, min
        a<max; b<max; c<max
        check a*b+c < max or not
        b>0; a>0, c>0
        */

        max_val = max_val  -c;

        //std::cout<<"new max input:  "<<a <<" , "<< c<<"   iter: "<<b << "    "<<max_val <<std::endl;

        //compare with a now
        if(a>max_val) return false;
        int cur_prod = 0;
        if(a==0) return true;
        for(;b>1;b--) {
            cur_prod += a;
           int curr_diff = max_val-cur_prod; 
            /*
            subtraction possible because 
                max_val>prod,
                max_val-prod>prod-prod 
                max_val-prod>0 ---1
                prod>0
                -prod<0
                max_val+(-prod )< max_val+0 [x+ (-ive quantity)<x ]
                max_val-prod<max_val --2
                from 1, 2
                0< max_val-prod < max_val ---3
                from 3, max_val-prod can be expressed in integer

            check if curr_diff still can hold a increment of a
            which means: curr_diff>a should hold, for a further a deduction in prod
                         5>6 fails
                            for ex of max_val = 59, a = 6 at b = 2 (9th iteration) prod = 54
                            you can't add 6 now, since it will cross definable limit
            only b-1 iterations
            because at i-1 th iteration, ith product formation is checked
            */
            //std::cout<<"check function for input:  "<<a <<" , "<< c<<"   iter: "<<b << " prod now = "
            //        << cur_prod << "   diff = " <<curr_diff<<"  is curr_dif<a "<<(curr_diff>a)<<std::endl;
            if(curr_diff<a) {
                //std::cout<<" not possible"<<std::endl;
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

public:
    int myAtoi(string str) {
      //code to trim string
      int i =0, end=str.length()-1;
      //std::cout<<i<<"    "<<end<<std::endl;
      while(i<end && str.at(i)==' ') {i++;continue;}
      while(end>-1 && str.at(end)==' ') {end--;continue;}  


      if(end<i) return 0;

      int sign=1;
      if(str.at(i)=='-') {sign = -1; i++;}
      else if(str.at(i)=='+') {i++;}


      string tr_str = str.substr(i, end-i+1);

      int num = 0;

       for(char& digit : tr_str) {
        if(digit<'0' || digit>'9') return num; // not convertable character - exit
        int c= digit-'0';
        if(sign==-1) {
            //std::cout<<"Evaluating "<<c<<std::endl;
            //number cannot be lower than INT_MIN
            // do a check of num * 10 - c 
            //num<0 already

            if(checkMin(num, 10, -c, INT_MIN))
                num = num*10 -c;
            else {
                num = INT_MIN;
                break;
            }
            //std::cout<<"number is"<<num<<std::endl;
        }
        else {
            if(checkMax(num, 10, c, INT_MAX))
                num = num*10 +c;
            else {
                num = INT_MAX;
                break;
            }
            //std::cout<<"number is"<<num<<std::endl;
        }
       }
       return num;


    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process.

Comment: the code uses a method, where checkMin, where no direct multiplication is performed until the result is validated. to be  greater than INT_MIN.